# ListView не сразу заполняется из SQLite

Tags: android, json, listview, android-sqlite

Задача такая - получить с сервера json, распарсить его, и заполнить данными SQLite, а потом уже из SQLite заполнить ListView.

Я вроде всё написал, но при первом запуске приложения ListView не заполняется, а если поменять ориентацию экрана или перезапустить приложение, то всё отображается так, как надо.

Прошу подсказать, как сделать так, чтобы при первом же запуске приложения ListView заполнялся данными из SQLite, которые запихиваются туда из json?

```
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Db mDbAdapter;
private Cursor mCursor;
private SimpleCursorAdapter mCursorAd;
private ListView mLv;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    new ParseTask().execute();
    simpleCursorAdapter();
}

public void simpleCursorAdapter(){
    mDbAdapter = new Db(this);
    mCursor = mDbAdapter.getAllItems();

    String[] from = new String[] { KEY_NAME, KEY_EMAIL };
    int[] to = new int[] { R.id.tvName, R.id.tvEmail };

    mCursorAd = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.item, mCursor, from, to, 0);
    mLv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv);
    mLv.setAdapter(mCursorAd);

    mDbAdapter.close();
}

private class ParseTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    String resultJson = "";

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // получаем данные с внешнего ресурса
        try {
            URL url = new URL("http://androiddocs.ru/api/friends.json");

            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            urlConnection.connect();

            InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                buffer.append(line);
            }

            resultJson = buffer.toString();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return resultJson;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String strJson) {
        super.onPostExecute(strJson);

        JSONObject dataJsonObj = null;

        try {
            dataJsonObj = new JSONObject(strJson);
            JSONArray friends = dataJsonObj.getJSONArray("friends");

            mDbAdapter.deldel();
            for (int i = 0; i < friends.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject friend = friends.getJSONObject(i);

                JSONObject contacts = friend.getJSONObject("contacts");

                String email = contacts.getString("email");

                mDbAdapter.insEmail(email);
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
}
```

А это класс - помощник:

```
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class Db {

public static final String TABLE_NAME = "people";
public static final String KEY_ID = "_id";
public static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
public static final String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "peopleDB";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

private DbHelper mDbHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase mDb;

public Db(Context context) {
    mDbHelper = new DbHelper(context);
}

public Cursor getAllItems() {
    mDb = mDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    return mDb.query(TABLE_NAME, null, null, null, null, null, null);
}

public String insEmail(String s){
    mDb = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(KEY_EMAIL, s);
    mDb.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
    mDb.close();
    return null;
}

public void deldel(){
    mDb = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    mDb.delete(TABLE_NAME, null, null);
    mDb.close();
}

public void close() {
    if (mDbHelper != null) mDbHelper.close();
    if (mDb != null) mDb.close();
}

public class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public DbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_NAME +" ("
                + KEY_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement,"
                + KEY_NAME + " text,"
                + KEY_EMAIL + " text" + ");");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
        this.onCreate(db);
    }
}
}
```

На всякий случай вот main.xml:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="ListView должен быть ниже"
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lv"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

А вот item.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="tvName" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvEmail"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:text="tvEmail" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Точно после перезапуска приложения ListView заполнен? У меня не получилось (использовались ваши файлы)

Comment: Да. Если покрутить экран или свернуть приложение, а потом снова запустить тапом на иконку ListView заполняется.

Comment: Странно, вы все файлы скопировали в том виде, как и запускаете сейчас? Просто у меня не работает.

Comment: Да, все файлы (ну, кроме строки package ...)

Comment: После добавления permission на интернет и у меня заработало)))

Comment: Совсем забыл про манифест :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Метод `simpleCursorAdapter()` вызывается у вас сразу после запуска `AsyncTask`, когда еще БД  не успела заполниться.

Для того, чтобы указанный метод вызвался, когда уже все готово, поставьте его вызов в самый конец вашего метода `onPostExecute(String strJson)` и откройте в нем БД. Тогда этот метод примет вид:

```
protected void onPostExecute(String strJson) {
        super.onPostExecute(strJson);

        JSONObject dataJsonObj = null;

        try {
            dataJsonObj = new JSONObject(strJson);
            JSONArray friends = dataJsonObj.getJSONArray("friends");

            mDbAdapter = new Db(MainActivity.this); // <-- new ----
            mDbAdapter.deldel();

            for (int i = 0; i < friends.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject friend = friends.getJSONObject(i);

                JSONObject contacts = friend.getJSONObject("contacts");

                String email = contacts.getString("email");

                mDbAdapter.insEmail(email);
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        simpleCursorAdapter(); // <-- new ---
    }
```

А из `onCreate()` вызов `simpleCursorAdapter()` уберите.

Comment: Не получается. Когда вставляю в конец метода, то приложение вылетает с ошибкой. Текста ошибки нет, так как я сейчас вынужден тестировать не на эмуляторе, а на смарте. Вставлял как после цикла, так и после catch - результат тот же.

Comment: @Erm А почему нет текста ошибки? Ну и что, что на смарте.

Comment: Так просто вылетает и все. Я даже и не знаю, где код ошибки посмотреть :(

Comment: @Erm В Android Studio смотрите вкладку Android monitor. То, что будет красным - ошибка. Правда там всего много обычно. Нужно выделять главное.

Comment: У меня тут слабый комп (даже эмулятор не тянет) и китайский смарт, который Android Studio не видит :(. Вот сижу просто закачиваю на смарт по проводу и запускаю на смарте. Все тестирование работает/не работает. Вот такие пироги.

Comment: @Erm А вы включили на смарте отладку по USB? И ответьте пож на мой второй вопрос.

Comment: Да, отладка по USB включена.

Comment: @Erm Может надо драйвер для смарта поискать. Просто у меня тоже слабый комп, но с запуском приложений на смарте проблем не возникало.

Comment: Наверное, Вы правы. Эту проблему надо решить - иначе это мучение в потёмках. Спасибо за уделённое время.

Comment: @Erm Был NullPointerException, так как открывалась еще не созданная БД. Ответ исправлен

Comment: Спасибо Вам огромное. Я непроходимо туп, но сегодня пойду спать в хорошем настроении :)

Comment: @Erm Не надо на себя наговаривать. Не за что:)